# Virtual Machine for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3b+, software-recommendation

I have found Exagear Desktop. It would work perfectly except for the fact that the RPI3 version is $30. Are there any other virtual machine software that would work on the Raspberry Pi that are free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org) and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) are both available for RPi. I have just checked with `apt-cache` on one of my RPis.

If what you intend is to emulate an x86 computer, either one will be slow as hell because they have to really emulate the x86 architecture without having at least low-level support for the x86 instruction set - so it has to be emulated "all the way".

Comment: You should expand upon the answer as it has been flagged as being somewhat terse. Maybe include the output of `apt-cache` and some links and descriptions of each, with pros and cons? Otherwise it might have been better suited as a comment

Comment: What do you mean? There are two VM software packages that are free.

Comment: Your post was in the *Low Quality Posts* review queue and *could* have been deleted as it was a one-liner - that is what I mean.

Comment: @eftshift0 VirtualBox shouldn't be available on the Pi as it's x86 only. QEMU will work though and can emulate x86 on ARM; it's the `qemu` package in the repos.

Comment: I will happily remove my downvote if you point me to the RPi version of VirtualBox, or relevant build instructions.